# Is css box-shadow part of element's box model?

Tags: html, css

Is `box-shadow` part of box? width of shadow will be included in total width of Block element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [box-shadow: shadow effect on elements in css3](https://web.archive.org/web/20130430151856/http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css3/box-shadow.html), **no**.

`box-shadow` applies to the outside of the box model unless you specify "inset".

Answer (score 9):

No, width of shadow is not included in the total width of the element.

And even if you specify inset, then the shadow will be inside the element, and in no way can contribute to the total width.