# CSS box-shadow appears only with margin

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

So, my website has a header and a div containing Revolution Slider immediately after it. I'm trying to add a box-shadow below the header - and above the slider. But it doesn't work, unless I also add `margin-bottom` to the header - but that renders the whole exercise moot.

This is the code:

```css
#header {
  display:block;
  min-height: 99px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 3px solid #8dddcd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 99px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#rev {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="rev">the slider</div>
```

Could someone help me figure out what's causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is css box-shadow part of element's box model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036498/is-css-box-shadow-part-of-elements-box-model)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the issue turned out to be related to `z-index` properties of the different divs. With some tweaking I managed to get it all sorted out without using any margin.

Anyway, thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: Can you explain what z-index properties you changed to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 10):

See the following questions:

- [Does css border-shadow add to an element's size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9620027/1366033)
- [Is css box-shadow part of element's box model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7036498/1366033)

According to the [box-shadow spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#box-shadow):

> An outer box-shadow casts a shadow as if the border-box of the element were opaque. The shadow is drawn outside the border edge only

So if you don't want overlap, you'll have to add the margin youself

```css
#header {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#slider {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="slider">Slider</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, KyleMit! The trouble is that once I set the slider div to `display:none`, the shadow appears without the need to add any margin anywhere. What property of the slider could be impeding the shadow of the header, any idea?

Comment: @zkvvoob, I'm not quite sure I understand your issue.  Can you update your question with a screenshot of what's actually happening and what you'd like to happen.  If it was just that you didn't need the `margin-bottom` when the slider was set to `display:none`, you could add a `margin-top` to the slider instead.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. See my answer at the bottom. Sorry for the troubles!

Answer (score 2):

If you need as you say the box-shadow below the header only and above the slider you can use minus in the last number in box shadow as the following:

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

This will make the box-shadow appear only at the bottom.

Working example:

```css
#header {
  display:block;
  min-height: 99px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 3px solid #8dddcd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 99px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#rev {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="rev">the slider</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the default rendering mode for box-shadow(outer shadow), you need to add a margin in that direction(10px on y-axis in your example) so the overflowed box content will be visible. 
If you want to display your box shadow inside the header, just add the keyword `inset` to your declaration.